# Getting feature datasets with arcpy.da.Walk

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, feature-dataset, walk

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0.

I'm trying to find feature datasets in file geodatabase (possibly many geodatabases, but for clarity here only one) using arcpy.da.Walk. I'm aware of workaround using ListDatasets, but for optimization reasons I'd prefer to use arcpy.da.Walk. It looks like Walk doesn't detect feature datasets as feature datasets (it treats them as "folders").

```
import os
workspace=r'E:\GIS_DATA\ArcGIS\TestWalk' #TestWalk.gdb with 2 datasets is inside this folder
feature_datasets = []

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,datatype=["FeatureDataset"])

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_datasets.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
print ("Found:{0}".format(feature_datasets))
```

It doesn't find any datasets. [Someone suggested to use dirnames](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/getting-feature-datasets-with-arcpy-da-walk-arcgis/m-p/1295763/highlight/true#M67789):

```
for dirname in dirnames:
    feature_datasets.append(os.path.join(dirpath, dirname))
```

But then obviously also Window folders are returned.

Edit:
There are quite a few possible workarounds. However for optimization reasons I'd like to stick to arcpy.da.Walk without any additional filtering (after all this is what datatype parameter should provide). So possible answer is that functionality of Arcpy.da.Walk is flawed and some workaround has to be used.

Edit 2:
@user2856 answer has been accepted as it is probably the fastest workaround. If someone is confused as I was, please read his comment regarding specifics of arcpy.da.Walk. "Bug or Feature" is an open question.

Comment: Your second line of code is wrong. `r'E:\GIS_DATA\ArcGIS\TestWalk'` does not refer to `#TestWalk.gdb` (and is likely not present, hence the lack of results)

Comment: @Vince  I read the code in question as stating that the `TestWalk.gdb` is inside the `TestWalk` folder. If so `arcpy.da.Walk` will find it.

Comment: @user2856 You're right. I didn't forget to include TestWalk.gdb there :)

Comment: Cross post : https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/getting-feature-datasets-with-arcpy-da-walk-arcgis/m-p/1295643#M67785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion to use directory names is technically correct.

`arcpy.da.Walk` considers a feature dataset to be a container (like a directory or a toolbox), and includes that in the [2nd output](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm) `dirnames`:

> `dirnames` is a list of names of subdirectories **and other workspaces** in `dirpath`.

These other workspaces can include feature datasets and toolboxes inside a geodatabase.  When you restrict by specifying `datatype="FeatureDataset"` you get a list of subdirectories and feature datasets.

Perhaps including subdirectories is a bug or perhaps it's intended.

Either way, you are not going to get a list of feature datasets in `Walk`'s 3rd output `filenames`:

> `filenames` is a list of names of **nonworkspace** contents in `dirpath`.

However, you will need to either test all directories to see if they're feature datasets (slow) or simply check if the parent is a file GDB or enterprise GDB connection:

```
workspace=r'D:\Temp\test' #test.gdb with 2 datasets is inside this folder
feature_datasets = []

for root, dirs, files in arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureDataset"):
    if os.path.splitext(root.lower())[-1] in (".gdb", ".sde"):
        for dirname in dirs:
            feature_datasets.append(os.path.join(root, dirname))

print(feature_datasets)
```

Output:

```
['D:\\Temp\\test\\test.gdb\\test_fd1', 'D:\\Temp\\test\\test.gdb\\test_fd2']
```

Comment: I don't fully agree that suggestion to use directory names is correct. In my case feature dataset is "final search product". Esri theoretically enables to filter out by feature dataset in datatype parameter. Please note that your current code will include other "directory" features (eg toolbox) if it is inside GDB. Of course we could test if found directory is feature dataset - but then I would expect that datatype parameter of arcpy.da.Walk should handle it. So basically my question could be narrowed to : is there any way to make datatype parameter work properly with feature dataset?

Comment: "*Please note that your current code will include other "directory" features (eg toolbox) if it is inside GDB.*". No, that's incorrect. It will only include feature datasets, because I specified `datatype="FeatureDataset"`. If I leave that out, *then* it will include toolboxes,  etc.

Comment: "No, that's incorrect". Yes, my mistake. And I fully agree with your last comment.

Comment: So I'd make minor correction to your code os.path.splitext(root)[-1].lower() - to prevent uppercase GDB being omitted. Being slave to the details: code could be technically broken by creating fake.gdb windows folder and putting subfolders there, but it isn't very likely :) Not worth of putting arcpy.Describe datatype check anyway. Thanks for your time and detailed explanations.

Comment: Code and answer updated to reflect comments.

Comment: If someone would like to apply this solution to other ArcGIS "internal workspaces" like Toolbox by changing the datatype parameter ( *`datatype = "Toolbox"`*) - it doesn't work when Toolbox is nested in Geodatabase. This time it seems to be obvious bug.